# how to set template page and load it using Eztemplate of Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI and i just want to set the default template page, I am now using a library called `Eztemplate`i tried to load the view by using the following code:

```
  `$this->template
        ->set('title','Home')
        ->load('view','index')
        ->render();`
```

but it's not working and it seems that all the files haven't been loaded. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure your `css` and `js` files directories are correct

```
    'asset_path'           => 'assets/urApp/',     
     // ex: assets/  ->  http://www.yourwebsite.com/codeigniter/base/url/assets/
    'asset_css_folder'     => 'css/',         // is added to asset_path
    'asset_js_folder'      => 'js/',          // include trailing slash
    'asset_views_folder'   => 'views/',       // include trailing slash
```

second, remember once you `load` some view you can't `render` again.

so your code should be sth like:

```
 $this->template
        ->set('title','Home')
        ->set('view','index')
        ->render();
```